# unable to bind the id using @DeleteMapping in RestController to delete an item from the list

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to fetch the data in this list to process the delete request using Postman:

I have created this list:

```
@Service
public class SchoolService {

    private List<School> SchoolLists = new ArrayList<School>();

    public SchoolService() {
        System.out.println("Service School is created");

        SchoolLists.add(new School(1, "The white hands Group");

        SchoolLists.add(new School(2,"The Yellow Hands"));
```

And here I am trying to delete an element from the list by id:

```
public void deleteSchool(Integer id){
        SchoolLists.remove(id);

        throw new RuntimeException("School not found for given ID = " + id);
    }
```

Here how I handle the deletion request in the RestController:

```
@RestController
public class SchoolController {

@Autowired
private SchoolService schoolService;

@DeleteMapping("/school/{id}")
    public void deleteSchool(@PathVariable Integer id )
    {
        SchoolService.deleteSchool(id);
    }
```

This is the error I am getting in postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH3Ui.png)

here is the error I got after removing the exception:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI2xx.png)

Comment: Did you tried to remove `throw new RuntimeException()`? I'm not an java expert but it seems that the exception is simply printed into postman.

Comment: Hi, the linked image has a bad quality. You can attach it into the post.
Why did you throw an exception in deleteSchool method?

Comment: It is not working still.

Comment: @MichelFoucault The exception to see what Id was called. Because I could not find the reason for the method not to work

Comment: You could print a info in the log, please attach the image into the post

Comment: I don't know how to do that @MichelFoucault

Comment: Take a look at here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I did it @MichelFoucault

Comment: Sorry, your code is unclear. The reponse shows the exception message launched. Remove the exception and log with System.out.println the id.

Comment: @MichelFoucault I had removed the exception and added System.out.print(); and I got index out of bound

Comment: So, Is the list empty? However ArraList object the delete method with ArrayList could be have  thread safe issues

Comment: @MichelFoucault I have added some items in the list but I can not bind them in the DeleteMapping request. I am new to this spring boot coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `@PostConstruct` annotation (see [the official reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle))
Move the list initialization from constructor to `init` method.

```
@Service
public class SchoolService {

    private List<School> SchoolLists = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<School>();

    @PostConstruct
    public init() {
        System.out.println("Service School is created");

        SchoolLists.add(new School(1, "The white hands Group");

        SchoolLists.add(new School(2,"The Yellow Hands"));
```

Use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for guarantee the thread safe support.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.